# Error while creating data frame from Rest Api in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a below pyspark code. I am reading a json data from Rest API and trying to load using pyspark.
But i couldnt read the data in DataFrame in spark.Can some one help me in this.

````
import urllib
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType

schema = StructType([StructField('dropoff_latitude',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('dropoff_longitude',StringType(),True),
                     StructField('extra',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('fare_amount',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('improvement_surcharge',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('lpep_dropoff_datetime',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('mta_tax',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('passenger_count',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('payment_type',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('pickup_latitude',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('ratecodeid',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('tip_amount',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('tolls_amount',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('total_amount',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('trip_distance',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('trip_type',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('vendorid',StringType(),True)
                    ])
url = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/pqfs-mqru.json'
data =  urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')

rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd,schema)
df.show()```

**The Error message is TypeError: StructType can not accept object '[' in type <class 'str'>**
** I have been able to do using dataset in scala but i am not able to understand why its not possible using python **
````

import spark.implicits._

// Load the data from the New York City Taxi data REST API for 2016 Green Taxi Trip Data
val url="https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/pqfs-mqru.json"
val result = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url).mkString

// Create a dataframe from the JSON data
val taxiDF = spark.read.json(Seq(result).toDS)

// Display the dataframe containing trip data
taxiDF.show()

Answer (score 0):

Just for others ..
Here is the code that worked for me .Request .get returns a list

```
import  requests
import json
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType

schema = StructType([StructField('dropoff_latitude',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('dropoff_longitude',StringType(),True),
                     StructField('extra',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('fare_amount',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('improvement_surcharge',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('lpep_dropoff_datetime',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('mta_tax',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('passenger_count',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('payment_type',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('pickup_latitude',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('ratecodeid',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('tip_amount',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('tolls_amount',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('total_amount',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('trip_distance',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('trip_type',StringType(),True),\
                     StructField('vendorid',StringType(),True)
                    ])
url = 'https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/pqfs-mqru.json'
r = requests.get(url)
data_json = r.json()
df = spark.createDataFrame(data_json,schema)
display(df)
```